# eclipse: external CDI in EJB module: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, cdi

My current project consisting of a war and  ejb module, is using a jar (incorperated via maven). This jar contains a CDI component which, when I inject this in the war module it works as expected, but when I inject this in my ejb module I get a NoClassDefFoundError during startup from my WAS 8.5 in eclipse (full profile).

When I start the server first, add the inject later and republish it seems to work. Also when I use Liberty profile it works. Also on Z/os and IPAS it works as expected.

I think it might has something todo with classloading, but have no idea how to solve this properly.

Using Eclipse Neon, WAS 8.5.5.11 full profile , jee6 
Project is using java 8 while the component is using java 6

This is the first part of the stacktrace:

[13-9-17 14:54:26:589 CEST] 0000003e InjectionProc W   CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the BestelFacade class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exc
eption : Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFieldsImpl(Native Method)

Thanks

Comment: Where is the JAR located in your deployment (ear/lib or war/lib)? What beans does it contain (pure CDI, or EJB stateless/stateful beans)? Also paste here your `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: The class file for the class is not available to the classloader trying to do this.  You most likely need to put it somewhere else.

Comment: @Siliarus The jar is just a maven dependency just like others. As far as I know it contains pure CDI beans (only annotation I used is @Dependent). For Error see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the job done, but I'm not sure if this is a proper solution or just a workaround while masking the real problem.

When I take a look at the ear module assembly I see in the source column c:/ws/.../jar and in the deploy path lib/jar

when I change the source into /..ear/target/../jar it works

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **`<bundleDir>/</bundleDir>`**
This will place the external jar/ejb not in lib, but in the root.

```
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              ...........
              <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
              <modules>
             
                 <jarModule>
                    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                    <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                 </jarModule>

               </modules>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
```